# SQL - EXISTS/NOT EXISTS function

Tags: sql, function, exists

I'm trying to learn SQL and I'm having a little trouble here.

```
 ID  |  P_Id |  room | 
======================
 1   |   8   |   A   |
 2   |   8   |   A   |
 3   |   8   |   B   |
 4   |   9   |   B   |
 5   |   9   |   B   |
 6   |   10  |   C   |
 7   |   10  |   C   |
 8   |   10  |   D   |
```

I'm trying to figure out which `P_Id` has **only** worked in room B. So the outcome would be `P_Id = 9`. Not 8 as well, because he worked in room A as well.

This is my query, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT Room.P_Id
FROM Room
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Room
                  WHERE Room.room <> 'B');
```

Could you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

You need to correlate the subquery with the outer query and use different aliases in the outer and inner queries, or the subquery will use the wrong table. The correlation makes sure the subquery applies to the correct row in the outer query (where the P_Id matches).

Do this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r1.P_Id
FROM Room r1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Room r2
  WHERE r2.room <> 'B'
    AND r1.P_Id = r2.P_Id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Select Room.P_Id
FROM Room
WHERE MIN(room.room) = MAX(room.room) and MIN(room.room) = 'B'
Group by Room.P_Id
```

There might be other more elegant ways, but this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select distinct p_ID 
from room 
where room = 'B' 
  and p_id not in (Select p_ID from room where room <> 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
SELECT DISTINCT P_Id FROM Room WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT P_Id FROM Room WHERE room <>'B');
```